# No new blocks with dockerized local RPC node

Tags: docker, block-production, wss, local

I want to run the substrate node locally(with docker) to use it as an RPC provider(via ws). I want to use "author.pendingExtrinsics" method as well as "chain.subscribeNewHeads" and other RPC methods and I'm expecting to see the real-time result. Is it possible? Which flags I should set for the docker container to achieve this?

I tried "--rpc-external --ws-external --rpc-cors=all --unsafe-ws-external --unsafe-rpc-external", but at some point, the node stopping to see new blocks(I can see recent events in the https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9944#/explorer, but the last block is not updated).